# How can I disable column auto-width feature in Clarity Datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

I need to dynamically build the columns of a [Clarity Datagrid](https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/structure) in Angular. This is how I do it:

I have an array `columnsDef` that holds the definition of the fields I need to show, like this:

```
columnsDef = [
{id:'id', label:'ID'},
{id:'client', label:'Client/Prospect'},
...
]
```

and another variable `backlog` that holds the actual data to show in the grid.

then, in my html template, I have the following code to define the columns headers and cells:

```
<clr-datagrid>
  <clr-dg-column *ngFor="let def of columnsDef" [clrDgField]="def.id">
     {{ def.label }}
  </clr-dg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let request of backlog" [clrDgItem]="request">
      <clr-dg-cell *ngFor="let def of columnsDef">
          {{ request[def.id] }}
      </clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

This actually "works" but the column alignment is all messed up. The values aren't below their headers and the cells width are different from row to row.
[image]

*(Sorry I had to pixelize some confidential data)*

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: You could apply style with specific `width` to columns - you may have to use same value for `clr-dg-column` and corresponding `clr-dg-cell`

Comment: I tried that, and it works as long as the user doesn't resize one header. When that happens, all the columns go back to their "weird" dimensions. I guess it has something to do with the datagrid auto-width feature.

Comment: I guess you will have to fixed width for all columns, and use some kind of word-wrap for columns that have really long values.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic columns don't get calculated widths because of the nature of the lifecycle, the contents aren't rendered in time to know what the size is so they get a default width. If you put a `[style.width.px]="100"` binding on each column it will easily select that size by default instead.

Another option that I'd recommend is defining all of the columns and then dynamically hiding the ones you don't want. That means the table is fully known to the Datagrid and calculations should be better.

```html
    <clr-dg-column>
        <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: isColumnHidden}">
            Column Name
        </ng-container>
    </clr-dg-column>
```

Some cases this might not make sense (as in sometimes columns are not meant to be available at all). In those cases I generally recommend to just define a different Datagrid for each case instead of trying to always have a dynamically built one. It makes it more explicit and declarative what the Datagrid is, and will render more cleanly.

Comment: Using clrDgHideableColumn sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work. The issue is that the structure of the grid is retrieved from a web service, so until the call to the API is resolved, the grid doesn't know its own structure.

Using  [style.width.px]="100" works at first, but when the user resize one column, then all the widths are recalculated wrongly

Is there a way to de-activate the auto-width?

Comment: I follow your hint about datagrid life cycle (and also checked the source code :-p) and I found a workaround. using *ngIf="gridDefinitionIsLoaded === true" on the datagrid element does the trick since the grid is not actually rendered until all the data is available. When it is, the grid lifecycle can calculate width correcty. It's not pretty but it works... for now..

Comment: That will defer if you are loading values async, so that is a viable workaround.

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround. I'd be glad to have a more elegant solution, though. Like, being able to execute de "calculate column with" function on demand instead of only on ngAfterViewInit, or disabling it, or disabling column resize. That would be great